# Checking domain name age through Java

Tags: java, dns

I am making a simple phishing scanner tool for a university project. One of my detection methods includes checking if the DNS within the email are valid, and I also want to check their age. This is example code of how I check if they are existing:

```
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.naming.directory.Attribute;
import javax.naming.directory.Attributes;
import javax.naming.directory.DirContext;
import javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext;
import java.util.Hashtable;

public class DNSExample {
    static int doLookup( String hostName ) throws NamingException {
        Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
        env.put("java.naming.factory.initial",
                "com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsContextFactory");
        DirContext ictx = new InitialDirContext( env );
        Attributes attrs =
                ictx.getAttributes( hostName, new String[] { "MX" });
        Attribute attr = attrs.get( "MX" );
        if( attr == null ) return( 0 );
        return( attr.size() );
    }

    public static void main( String args[] ) {

        String [] array = {"google.com","dsad33114sssaxzx.com"} ;
        for( int i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ) {
            try {
                System.out.println( array[i] + " has " +
                        doLookup( array[i] ) + " mail servers" );
            }
            catch( Exception e ) {
                System.out.println(array[i] + " : " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> How would I need to modify the above code to include a check of age
>   for servers that exist?

Comment: Are you thinking of trying to get this information via WHOIS? If so, different WHOIS servers are notoriously inconsistent in their output formats so you're going to end up with a lot of different patterns to parse for.

Comment: From some reading I did it was suggested that I use WHOIS. I was wondering if there is a central source I can use through java. Ideally it would not be too troublesome as its only a small feature of the application.

Comment: There is no central source. Each different domain registry operates its own WHOIS servers, and most (all?) domain registrars also operate their own WHOIS server. Worst of all, it is possible that some domain registries don't operate one at all. And, as I said, their output formats are mostly all different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've chosen a problem that cannot be solved in the general case ... using current generation internet standards:

1. The information you need cannot be obtained from DNS itself.
2. In some cases information about DNS registrations can be obtained from WHOIS.  However, the information returned by WHOIS servers is not standardised:

   - There is no standard information model.
   - There is no standard format.
   - There are no guarantees as to the accuracy of the information.
   - It is not even clear if "age of server" is going to be available.  (For instance, the closest that APNIC's WHOIS provides to that is the last modification timestamp for the DNS record.  And that is NOT a good proxy for server age.)
3. There is a set of RFC's that define something called [CRISP](http://www.ietf.org/wg/concluded/crisp), but as far as I can make out the purpose of that standard is for registrar to registrar exchange of information.  (I couldn't find any public-facing services based on CRISP.)
4. There is also an IETF working group called [WEIRDS](http://datatracker.ietf.org/wg/weirds/charter/) which I think is intended to define a web-enabled replacement for WHOIS.  (Don't confuse WEIRDS with the IETF WEIRD WG!)  But that was formed very recently, and it is too soon to make any predictions of the outcome.  (Or how long it will take for the NICs to implement any specs that come out of the WG.)

---

Summary: your chances of implementing something in this space that really works are currently low.  Probably the best you can hope to achieve is something based on screen-scraping one or two WHOIS services.

This might change in a few years, but that is of no help for your current project.

Answer (score 1):

It seems based on your description and comments above you are trying to gather whois information.

1. download APIs from http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/
2. change the nameToQuery below and run it.

public class WhoisIt {

```
public static final String WHOIS_SERVER = "whois.internic.net";
public static final int WHOIS_PORT = 43;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String nameToQuery = "avajava.com";

    WhoisClient whoisClient = new WhoisClient();
    whoisClient.connect(WHOIS_SERVER, WHOIS_PORT);
    String results = whoisClient.query(nameToQuery);

    System.out.println(results);
}
}
```

good luck

Comment: Tried downloading from http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/download_net.cgi and File not found is returned from main and other mirrors... Although I got a copy of 3.1 that should do for now.

Comment: try version commons-net-3.2-bin.zip , http://apache.mirrors.lucidnetworks.net//commons/net/binaries/commons-net-3.2-bin.zip